# Vertically Center a Paragraph

Tags: html, css

I have a problem, I am not able to vertically align my text, I tried searching and I didn't find any solution for my problem.

I am trying to make a Nav, which you can hover on it will scale up the nav height with a transition, but my text which is in this Div won't be able to center vertically.

Here is my css

```
.nav-links-typo {
    font-size: 17px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
}
.nav-bar {
    position: fixed;
    height: 3%;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    background-color: coral;
    transition: 1.2s;
}
.nav-bar:hover {
    height: 5%;
    transition: 1.2s;
}
.nav-links-block {
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 10%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    background-color: lightgray;
    display: inline-table;
    text-align: center;
}
```

and here is my html

```
<div class="nav-bar">

    <div class="nav-links-block-platzhalter"></div>

    <div class="nav-links-block">

        <a class="nav-links-typo">Startseite</a>

    </div>

    <div class="nav-links-block">

        <a class="nav-links-typo">Rest API Console</a>

    </div>

    <div class="nav-links-block">

        <a class="nav-links-typo">Grafana</a>

    </div>



</div>
```

Comment: http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/

Comment: I put your code in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7ms267jy/), but still not clear for me what you want to achieve.

Comment: @BogdanC https://jsfiddle.net/y4vf4gLj/ The Problem had been that, if i hover over the div "nav-bar" the text in "nav-links-typo" is gonna stay in the same Position. But i figured out how i do fix it, look at my answer beyond :) But thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out myself:
instead of setting the height i am gonna add an padding to top and bottom.

```
.nav-bar:hover {
    padding-top: 1%;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
    transition: 1.2s;
}
```